# "sudo pip list" and "pip list" inside virtual environment gives a different result

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I can't figure this out. Maybe one of you guys in the community can.

I've been testing the Python virtual environments, specifically with the inheritance of the installed site packages when a virtual environment is created.

So my global python is:

```
$ sudo python -V 
Python 3.9.5
```

Same when omitting the `sudo` command and running the version command as a normal user:

```
$ python -V
Python 3.9.5
```

After knowing this, I created a test virtual environment. Just like this:

```
$ python -m venv test_venv --system-site-packages
```

Next, the activation and the sanity check:

```
$ source test_env/bin/activation
$ (test_venv) [me@pc 11:43 me]$ python -V
Python 3.9.5
```

What I would have expected inside the new environment is that the same packages used by the global python installation would be listed, but this doesn't seem to be the case. For starters, there are more inside the `venv` when compared with the global `pip` list.

```
$ sudo pip list | wc -l
17

$  pip list | wc -l
19

$(test_venv) [me@pc 12:17 me]$ pip list | wc -l
80
```

And there is a different version used compared to the global installation.

```
venv     :      zeroconf        0.28.8
sudo pip :      zeroconf        0.28.5
user pip :      zeroconf        0.28.5
```

And there are other packages which are not visible in the pip list like:

```
toml       0.10.2
sip        4.19.25
```

Where are these packages coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer to my own question.

It turns out **the packages only need to be present** inside the site packages folder to get included inside the virtual environment.
It has nothing to do with the installed packages present under "pip list".

But when the virtual environment was created the installer also looks at your local site package folder and takes the **newest packages**.

```
/usr/lib/<Your current python version>/site-packages

~/.local/lib/<Your current Python version>/site-packages
```

So, I had a newer version of zeroconf inside my local site-package folder and in the global folder all sort of packages which where never installed by pip.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer that you already posted, if you take a look at the [Python3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#module-venv) you can see that

> The venv module provides support for creating lightweight “virtual environments” with their own site directories, optionally isolated from system site directories.

This provides the advantage of allowing the user to have an isolated environment that isn't affected by global packages, and that's why you're seeing a different list of packages inside your virtual environment.